# How to write "@" in android emulator ?

Tags: android, keyboard, virtual

I have a MAC and with OPT-ò (italian keyboard layout) I can write "@" in ALL application but not in "Android emulator". I don't want to press "char per char" via virtual keyboard in my app. Is it possibile (and how) write "@" without virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 17):

You can add english keyboard and use shift+2 with keyboard switching. Not so cool but you can do it without mouse.

Or if you need input long text may be easier is use adb

`adb shell input text 'type\ text\ here'`

Comment: Add keyboard in emulator or in Mac ?

Comment: Any other way?? Seems stupid not being able to write "@" like in any other application.. My keyboard layout is Spanish, so I use Alt-2 to write "@".

Answer (score 12):

Alt + 64 works too, I'm using spanish keyboard

Comment: I.e. holding down ALT while writing 64 on the numerical keyboard. Thanks for reminding me of this old trick!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ALT-2 to write "@" (or Option-2 on Mac), use Shift-2.

Tested in a Macbook Pro with spanish keyboard running [Andy Android emulator](https://www.andyroid.net/).

Answer (score 0):

change keyboard layout to English (US) in emulator settings

Answer (score 0):

For me, clicking on the textfield made it, the native keyboard popped up.